# when purchasing an SSL certificate, does it automatically come with a root and intermediate?

Tags: security, ssl, encryption, ssl-certificate

I have done extensive research on this topic and my knowledge is still pretty ambiguous. I'm looking to get a basic DV for a simple site, but I see every SSL online has three levels, Root->Intermidiate (that acts as a proxy for the Root ) and a regular certificate i guess?

Here is Googles:

[image]

I see their Root is issued from GeoTrust but their intermediate is one of their own, so do you purchase the root separately or does it come with the purchase of an SSL? and Does the root create the intermediate thus signing the purchased SSL or? Some clarity would be nice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A certificate serves two purposes:

- Encrypt connection
- Prove that the site owner is who claims to be

If we were just going to encrypt data any certificate would do (even a self-signed) but that's not enough in real life because we also need to ensure that we aren't connecting to a fake site (there's no point in keeping information secure and then deliver it to the bad guys) and that's where the trust chain concept comes in. In your example:

1. You have a certificate for `www.google.com`, but you can't really say whether it's genuine. After all, anyone can generate a cert for `www.google.com`.
2. Someone who claims to be Google guarantees that the above certificate is genuine, but you can't really say whether they are the real Google.
3. Someone who claims to be GeoTrust guarantees that the above certificate has been really issued to the real Google. But this time you trust GeoTrust because it is configured as root authority in your browser. Either it comes with the browser (and you trust your browser) or you installed the CA yourself (that's typical in Spain when you need to access government sites).

It's also worth noting that we could have an arbitrary number of levels, not necessarily three.

To sum up:

- You don't own any certificate in the trust chain except the last one you've paid for.
- The company you get the cert from should have already done all the paperwork to be part of the bundled CAs in major browsers (after all, they charge for the service). Otherwise, your site visitors will get an *untrusted certificate* error message because they won't have the root CA.
- Optionally, you might need to download and install some additional *intermediate* certificates (but you still don't own them).

Comment: okay so to relay my understanding on the three certs existence and their roles in the chain of trust: the cert you pay for signifies a secure connection however being that this isn't suffice, there is a root cert that is issued by a trusted CA ( registered in the browser as a trusted CA?) and being that the root should never be fully exposed, the intermediate acts as a proxy to sign the cert you paid for?

Comment: Your cert is used to do the actual work (sign/encrypt), all others are used to validate the certs that depend on them.

Comment: I understand you need a specific SSL to secure subdomains, but what about inner pages within your site? As in 'mywebsite.com/about' or 'mywebsite.com/info' , does it also secure these pages? Or just the index page?

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple, when you order SSL certificate from vendor or Certificate Authority. CA will provide a zip file that contains root, intermediate and primary certificate. The reason behind to install root certificate is to avoid the browser warnings generally occurred while visiting website. You don’t need to order above mentioned certificate individually as it comes altogether.

The reason behind intermediate certificate is to create a chain of trust between browser of visitors and the web server. All three certificates should be copy and paste in a simple text file (check below example) and to be placed on server that will be used while installing the SSL later on. Hope this will clear your doubts.

**Example**:

```
—–BEGIN CERTIFICATE—–

(Primary certificate: yourdomain.crt)

—–END CERTIFICATE—–

—–BEGIN CERTIFICATE—–

(Intermediate certificate: ca.crt)

—–END CERTIFICATE—–

—–BEGIN CERTIFICATE—–

(Root certificate: root.crt)

—–END CERTIFICATE—–
```

Comment: I understand you need a specific SSL to secure subdomains, but what about inner pages within your site? As in 'mywebsite.com/about' or 'mywebsite.com/info' , does it also secure these pages? Or just the index page?

Comment: Of-course directory will be covered. So **everything after** domain.com/ will be protected as well.